# Sending an Email in ASP.NET Web Application. (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I'm trying to send an email when a user clicks a button. However, I'm getting an exception like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekR82.png).

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
Partial Class _Default Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage("group2istn@gmail.com", "ndumisosizwe@gmail.com")
            mailMessage.Subject = "Mail Body"
            mailMessage.Body = "This is a test email"
            Dim SmtpClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential("group2istn@gmail.com", "myPasswordHere")
            SmtpClient.Credentials = credentials

            SmtpClient.EnableSsl = True
            SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
            MsgBox("Email sent successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Email Failed !  " & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like a security exception. Make sure port 587 is opened for communication, if it is a server will be blocked by default.
or  it might be server firewall  problem which is blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely correct . Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology , Which makes your account more vulnerable .

So,Gmail by default prevents access for your e-mail account from custom applications.

Login to your gmail account and **trun on** access for **less secure apps** .

Use this [Link](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=accountsettings&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps&followup=https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps&emr=1&mrp=security#identifier) to login. This redirects you to **Less secure apps** . Just make sure you have selected **trun on** and click back arrow near Less secure apps.

This way worked for me too . For furthur information refer [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)